# Prove that $C_{R}$ and $C_{r}$ are topologically equivalent for any $R\gt r\gt 0$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $C_{R}$ be the circle centered at $a$ of radius $R\gt 0$. Prove that $C_{R}$ and $C_{r}$ are topologically equivalent for any $R\gt r\gt 0$.

I just begin to study topology. This is the problem in my homework. I know that we need to find a bijective function $f:C_{R}\to C_{r}$ such that $f$, $f^{-1}$ are continuous.   But I'm not really know how to do.

Comment: What does "circle" mean?

Comment: ${(x,y)\in \Bbb {R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{y}=R^{2}}$

Comment: I would start with a picture and guess $f$ and its inverse, and then come up with an easy-to-describe  neighborhood base for the one circle and show how $f^{-1}$ maps it to a neighborhood base for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** consider the following definition of a circle (or more generally a sphere):

$$C_r=\big\{v\in\mathbb{R}^n\ \big|\ \lVert v\rVert=r\big\}$$

And now for any $r,t>0$ consider

$$f_{r,t}:C_r\to C_t$$
$$f_{r,t}(v)=\frac{t}{r}v$$

Comment: oh...thank you! I got it